# Preserve encoding of each byte while converting from stream to string

Tags: c#, stream

I have a scenario where I have data in a stream encoded with mix of encodings like utf-8, shift-jis etc. Some of the field are encoded with utf-8 and some with different encoding.
While converting from stream to string using StreamReader class, its converting everything taking one default encoding and hence we are sometimes loosing some chars in string.

I am using below lines for the conversion

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream,Encoding.Default);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

but I am loosing some data in string.

Comment: If you have mixed encodings, you have to isolate each segment with a different encoding, and apply the correct encoding to each segment separately.

Comment: "*Some of the field are encoded with utf-8 and some with different encoding*" - you should find the people responsible for this and suggest they need to rethink their life choices. Unless you have explicit information about where the encoding is used and why, you are fighting a losing battle

Comment: Please [edit] the question with information how those segments with different encodings are separated in the file so someone can provide an answer. Side note: when providing sample code please try to avoid worst possible practices like SQL injection, parsing XML with regex or using [Encoding.Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_Default) - such code tends to derail questions quickly even if otherwise the question has enough information.